# cellclassname to change the color of jquery grid cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
var rowCellClass = function (row, columnfield, value, rowData) {
    if (rowData.ConfirmDate != null && rowData.ConfirmDate != '') {
        return 'green';
    }
}
```

and this grid:

```
var gridPreDocWar = function (data) {
    var gridDataPreDocWar = generateConfirmations(1);
    var source ={
        totalrecords: gridDataPreDocWar.length,
        localData: gridDataPreDocWar,
        datafields:[
            { name: 'RecordId', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'ConfirmDate', type: 'date' },

        ],
        datatype: "array",
    };
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $("#grid").jqxGrid({
        
        theme: "ui-redmond",
        width: '100%',
        autoheight: true,
        source: dataAdapter,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
        columns: [
            { text: 'Updated', datafield: 'ConfirmDate', columntype: 'date', filtertype: 'input', width: '10%', cellsformat: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm', cellclassname: rowCellClass },
            
        ]
    });
}
```

I can see that ConfirmDate is not null or empty, but cellclassname function doesn't change the color of the cell. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to add css class

```
.green {
       color: #50C878;
       }
```